# Changing the values of previous months

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting, selectedvalue

I have to display same number of days in month and days gone for previous months and days left as zero when selecting any other months from financial year as i have only values of current date.

I dont have idea.I tried several ways but could not get

Answer (score 0):

You have to [use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gw0t4TKkzE4) the **month-to-date** and the **same-period-last-month**  .

I just replied to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668401/growth-for-top-15-retailers/76669153#76669153) that looks similar but for the year-to-date.

The logic is the same and you can find the month-to-date option in the Quick Measures.