# Growth % for top 15 retailers

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I want to show sales growth percentages v/s same period last year for a set of retailers in a line chart. the x axis is years (2023,2022,2021...)
There should be 3 lines,

1. Overall growth % of all retailers
2. Growth % of a specific retailer
3. Growth % of TOP15 retailers

Top 15 is calculated based on 2023, current year sales for retailers

Im able to write measures for showing overall and a specific retailer. Not able to write for top 15.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's doable.

Go to **Quick Measure** and find Year-to-date total:

[image]

This will be our first measure.

Then use the [SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax) function and you now have 2 metrics:

- this year Year-to-date total
- last year Year-to-date total

Now you can go back to **Quick Measure** and you can use:

- Quick Measure > Mathematical operations > Subtraction
- Quick Measure > Mathematical operations > Percentage difference

And you are done.